# How to implement group-membership JavaScript policy in Keycloak

Tags: javascript, keycloak

A [2-year old keycloak-user list question](http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2016-July/007069.html) w/o an answer:

1. there’s a protected resource called *Project*
2. and an owner - a *Project Manager*
3. Each project manager has access to only their own projects (owner-only policy).
4. Project Managers in turn report to one or more *Portfolio Managers*. A Portfolio Manager should be able to access all his/her project managers' projects (portfolio-manager policy).

Let’s assume the system design if flexible and this fact who are the Portfolio Managers for a particular Project Manager
can be either kept inside Keycloak (but not as keycloak [groups](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#groups)) or in the client app itself. How can this be implemented as a [JavaScrtipt-based
authorization policy](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/4.4/authorization_services/index.html#_policy_js) in Keycloak? I guess the request can be injected with this info somehow but can’t figure it out from the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be rather easy. I've decided to keep the info about managers in another database, and then the app (`service-nodejs`) needs to pass this info as a claim to keycloak. I've tested this on the [service-nodejs keycloak quickstart](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/service-nodejs). Here are the relevant pieces:

```
// app.js route:

app.get('/service/project/:id',
  keycloak.enforcer(['Project'], {
      response_mode: 'permissions', 
      claims: (request) => {
          return { "portfolio.managers": ['alice', 'bob'] } //hard-coded
      }
  }), function(req, res) {
      res.json({ message: `got project "operation "` });
  });
```

The policy protecting the Project resource is an aggregated of OwnerOnly and PortfolioManagers:

```
// portfolio-managers-policy:

var context = $evaluation.getContext();
var identity = context.getIdentity();
var userid = identity.getAttributes().getValue('preferred_username').asString(0);
var managers =  context.getAttributes().getValue('portfolio.managers')

if (!managers) {
    print('managers not provided, cannot decide!');
    $evaluation.deny();
} else {
    // check if the user is one of the portfolio managers of this project:
    for (var i = 0; i < managers.size(); i++) {
        if (managers.asString(i) == userid) {
            $evaluation.grant();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the `service-nodejs` keycloak client **must** be *confidential* in order to call the token endpoint.